# Pasting character values in a character string in front of a print message in R

Tags: r, string, character

I am having trouble pasting a character string in front of a print message.  Specifically I have: `> notinld
[1] "b3" "b2"` as character value to paste in front of a print message.
I have the following code with results:

```
> print(paste(notinld,"have not been included in the analysis due to all participants at this node for these items answering essentially the same",sep=" ",collapse=""))
[1] "b3 have not been included in the analysis due to all participants at this node for these items answering essentially the sameb2 have not been included in the analysis due to all participants at this node for these items answering essentially the same"
```

I am not sure why b2 is appearing in the middle of the message like that, and I would whichever character values that are in 'notinld' to appear in front of the print message with a comma between them such as:

```
b2,b2 "print message"
```

Thank you!

Comment: Run `paste(c('a','b'),c('d'))` and you'll see why it's happening.

Comment: ...more to the point, as written in the documentation: "If the arguments are vectors, they are concatenated term-by-term to give a character vector result. Vector arguments are recycled as needed, with zero-length arguments being recycled to ""."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `sprintf` here:

```
sprintf("%s have not been included", paste(notinld, collapse = ", "))
#"b3, b2 have not been included"
```